# Use the get_terms slug as a term for tax_query

Tags: plugins, php, custom-taxonomy

Update:

```
?>
    <div class="four-sixths first">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="one-sixth first">
                    <?php
                    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<img src="' . plugins_url('_images/food-placeholder.png', dirname(__FILE__)) . '" />';
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="five-sixths"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
            <?php endwhile;
                genesis_posts_nav();
            else: ?>
            <p>Sorry, there are no recipes available.</p>

            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to query like this. Displaying posts from the correct category when visiting `/recipe-categories/bread` is the default behaviour.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I kinda figured that - So I've updated the answer with the has_posts() loop, which I in fact do get my posts based on the slug. However, in the reading section of the settings, I have `Blog pages show at most` set at 3 which is what I want on the homepage, but I want to show 50 posts on the custom taxonomy page, which also only shows 3 now - Can that be overwritten?

Comment: Works like a charm - @JacobPeattie, you da man.